# Concatenation of tsvectors results in a syntax error in Postgres 9.4.6

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, lateral-join

When concatenating tsvectors from setweight in an SQL query, it throws a syntax error:

> ```
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "||"
> ```

It works fine if I try it with a single tsvector returned by `setweight`, and if I try to wrap the entire thing in another `to_tsvector` call, it errors with the reason that there is no `to_tsvector(tsvector)` function, so the concatenation is indeed forming a tsvector.

```
SELECT *, ts_rank_cd(textsearch, query) AS score
FROM products, plainto_tsquery('awesome shirt') query, 
   setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(title, '')), 'A') ||
   setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(description, '')), 'B') ||
   setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(tags, '')), 'C') ||
   setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(vendor, '')), 'D') textsearch
WHERE shop_url='somedomain.com' AND query @@ textsearch
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

I've tried wrapping it in a subquery, but that makes it a record, which causes issues with `ts_rank_cd`, since it's expecting `textsearch` to be of type tsvector. How can I get this concatented tsvector to work in this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the columns `title`, `description` etc are supposed to refer back to the table `products` ...

The syntax error you see is unrelated to text search per se. This should work:

```
SELECT *, ts_rank_cd(textsearch, query) AS score
FROM   products
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL plainto_tsquery('awesome shirt') query
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(title      , '')), 'A')
       || setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(description, '')), 'B')
       || setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(tags       , '')), 'C')
       || setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(vendor     , '')), 'D')
   ) ts (textsearch)
WHERE  ...
```

#### Why?

Because this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM   products, plainto_tsquery('awesome shirt') query ...
```

is an implicit `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` in the `FROM` clause. Omitting the `LATERAL` keyword is allowed for ***functions***. And the comma is mostly (see link at the end) equivalent to a `CROSS JOIN`.

Would work for this, too:

```
SELECT ...
FROM   products
     , plainto_tsquery('awesome shirt') query
     , setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(title, '')), 'A')  -- just another function
...
```

Hence:

> It works fine if I try it with a single tsvector returned by setweight

**But** the same short syntax is ***not*** allowed for other ***expressions*** like `setweight(...) || setweight(...)`. Those need to be wrapped in a `SELECT` statement which requires an explicit `LATERAL` keyword to allow the reference to a "lateral" table in the `FROM` list. Like demonstrated above. Or, shorter:

```
SELECT *, ts_rank_cd(textsearch, query) AS score
FROM   products
     , plainto_tsquery('awesome shirt') query
     , LATERAL (
   SELECT setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(title      , '')), 'A')
       || setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(description, '')), 'B')
       || setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(tags       , '')), 'C')
       || setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(vendor     , '')), 'D')
   ) ts (textsearch)
WHERE  ...
```

Related answer with more explanation for both `CROSS JOIN` and `LATERAL`:

- [What does [FROM x, y] mean in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167201/what-does-from-x-y-mean-in-postgres/167217#167217)

Comment: Thank you! That seems to work now. That explains why the single function calls were not causing syntax errors.