# PostgreSQL Trigger function won't work on insert row for text search column

Tags: postgresql, triggers, full-text-search, plpgsql, generated-columns

I have a pgsql `trigger` and a `trigger function`. Works when updating a previous record and does not work when inserting a new record. Ideally, the `text_search` column should be populated with the `tsvector` data mentioned.

The `id` column of the table `idea` is of `bigserial` and some of the other fields added to text_search are `nullable` if that's important.

Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_idea_text_search
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON prod.idea
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION prod.update_idea_text_search();
```

Trigger Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prod.update_idea_text_search()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
 
DECLARE text_search TSVECTOR;
BEGIN
   SELECT
 ((
       setweight(to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(title, ''::text)), 'A'::"char") ||
       setweight(to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(subtitle, ''::text)), 'A'::"char") ||
       setweight(to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(strategy, ''::text)), 'A'::"char") ||
       setweight(to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(summary, ''::text)), 'B'::"char") ||
       setweight(to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(conditions, ''::text)), 'B'::"char") ||
       setweight(to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(strategy_data::text, ''::text)), 'B'::"char") ||
       setweight(to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(tags::text, ''::text)), 'A'::"char") ||
       setweight(to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(id::text, ''::text)), 'B'::"char") ||
       setweight(to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(buy::text, ''::text)), 'C'::"char") ||
       setweight(to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(sell::text, ''::text)), 'C'::"char")
    ))
 INTO text_search 
   FROM
      prod.idea
   WHERE
      idea.id = NEW.id;
                                                                                                    
NEW.text_search := coalesce(text_search, '');
                                                                                                    
RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$;
```

If any more information is required let me know and other comments/suggestions are welcome!

Comment: This `BEFORE` and `idea.id = NEW.id;` are not going to work for an INSERT as the `id` value does not exist yet in the `prod.idea` table.

Comment: Just assign the to_tsvector()  output directly to `text_search`. Probably easiest way is to eliminate the `... FROM    prod.idea   WHERE   idea.id = NEW.id` portion of the query.

Comment: Just realized I should have added that the `COALESCE(title, ...)` portions will need to specify the `NEW` record, so `COALESCE(NEW.title, ...)`.

Comment: Yes you are correct it worked! Removed prod.idea table portion and  added new in front of the incoming parameters title, subtitle ..etc. Post it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: *"... some of the other fields added to text_search are nullable if that's important"* Yes, that's important. Lead with a `CREATE TABLE` statement showing data types and constraints. And *always* your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

[Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver) already helped with the syntax issues in your trigger function.

More fundamentally - in **Postgres 12** or newer - use a `STORED` [**generated column**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) instead of the trigger solution. Much cheaper and much less error prone! See:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)

So your table definition looks like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE idea (
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY
, title text
, subtitle text
-- , more ...
, text_search tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
      setweight(to_tsvector('english', COALESCE(title     , '')), 'A')
   || setweight(to_tsvector('english', COALESCE(subtitle  , '')), 'B')
-- || more ...
   ) STORED  -- !!
);
```

`COALESCE` only for nullable columns, obviously.
The text search index you'll have with it:

```
CREATE INDEX idea_text_search_gin_idx ON idea USING GIN (text_search);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9LJbc0DY)

Your queries stay the same.

Related:

- [How to get rid of a Bitmap Heap Scan if the table already has the proper indices](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/217263/3684)
- [Concatenation of tsvectors results in a syntax error in Postgres 9.4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51774846/concatenation-of-tsvectors-results-in-a-syntax-error-in-postgres-9-4-6/51777624#51777624)
- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)